# Is there a way to loop over array of arrays of objects?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is how my solution should look like:

[image]

Right now I have an array where I group them all by there first letter like so

```
const grouped = _.groupBy(topicPages, key => key.relatedTopic.title[0]);
```

And this is the result :

[image]

[image]

So I am trying to figure out a way to display the Letter A with the titles that are in that array.

I have tried using some sort of map :

```
grouped.map(first, key) => {
  // here I want to display the key

 // and then continue looping over 
  first.map(title => {
    title.relatedTopic.title
  })
})
```

Comment: `_.forEach()` over it, since you're using Lodash. Or use any of the other Lodash methods that work here like `_.entries()` or something. Or loop over `Object.entries()` without Lodash. How you display those results seems like a separate issue, though.

Comment: Please replace the images with a text example?

Comment: you mentioned > I have tried using some sort of map , then?

Comment: I get : TypeError: grouped.map is not a function

Comment: Thanks, I will update my question to try and describe my problem better!

Comment: It would be helpful to see an example of your `topicPages` input - but as code not a screenshot remember

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I get : TypeError: grouped.map is not a function

`grouped` is an object, which does not have a `map` function.

```js
const input = ["All","Andre","Ben","Boy"];

const grouped = _.groupBy(input, item => item[0]);

console.log(grouped)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

In order to loop over it you probably want the `entries`

```js
const input = ["All","Andre","Ben","Boy"];

const grouped = _.groupBy(input, item => item[0]);

_.forEach(_.entries(grouped), ([key,values]) => {
    console.log(key);
    values.forEach(value => {
       console.log("\t" + value);
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @PeterSeliger you could imply their structure from `key.relatedTopic.title` in the question, but this answer does not need to understand their structure - it describes the required implementation of iterating a grouped object

Comment: `_.forEach` already loops over keys and values of an object. But puts the key as second parameter. Your code is equivalent to `_.forEach(grouped, (values, key) => /*no further changes needed*/` [Demo](https://jsbin.com/nabojun/1/edit)

Comment: Thanks @VLAZ that's what I should have done

Comment: @Jamiec Can I ask why key and value is wrapped inside brackets? I can't figure out what is does

Comment: @EirikVattøy it destructures the array. `_.entries` returns an array like `[key.value]` and that just destructures it to variables `key` and `values`. More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment